# Is a best common way to solve button click too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button.when click button, show a dialog to select data.
If click the button so fast,multi dialog will be show.
At present，I have two way to solve this problem
1.use disabled
2.use setTimeout and clearTimeout

have any other better way to solve this problem?
thank you very much

explain:
if use disabled,after dialog close,need to set the button available.
at present,I use this code

```
Util.prototype.lazyTriggerEvent = function(buttonId,event,callback){
    var searchTrigger=null;
    $("#"+buttonId).bind(event,function(){
        var text = $.trim($(this).val());
        clearTimeout(searchTrigger);
        searchTrigger = setTimeout(function(){
            callback(text);
        },500);
    })
};
//Util.lazyTriggerEvent("showDialgBtnId","click",function(){})
```

if click button trigger a ajax，and have much more button like this，is a best common way to solve this problem.

Comment: use `.one()` only 1 click will happened some thing like `$('#btnid').one(function(){//code here})`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to leave it disabled until the associated dialog is closed? (Rather than a timeout-based solution, which presumably could re-enable it while the dialog is still open.)

Comment: @guradio After select data and close dialog，need click again to select data for update

Comment: unbind then bind click if you need click again

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery's `.one()` handler which limits a function to running once:

[JQuery's .one() handler](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$('button').one('click', function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

---

Or you can also disable the button on click:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  // Do stuff
});
```

To re-enable the button, you can simply add the following to your close modal function:

```
$('button').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: thank you,this button need click again.not click once

Comment: you can reenable the button whenever you want.

Comment: @Eric Guan    Usually,need reenable the button after close dailog.if  have more button like this,the code will......

Comment: @YingYi With my second option, you can simply enable it with `$('button').prop('disabled', false);` whenever you need to. Perhaps add that to your close modal function. Answer updated.

Comment: @Derek Story Use this way,will have much more set `true` and `false`code in  project.I don't want that.I want code clean and beautiful.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I would consider that quite a bit cleaner than adding `setTimout` throughout your project when it isn't needed. I'm not sure what you mean by true and false making it not "beautiful". It would be tough to write quality JS without booleans.

Comment: The .one function is the best. Then just add code in the 'hide' or 'close' event handler of your dialog. Question: Why don't you simply use a modal window? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: @Derek Story Before dialog show,need to set the button disabled,after dialog close need to set the button available(dialog close button and top right corner `X`).have three place to controll button status.when a page have three this select data button,have nine place to controll button status.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose when you want to show a dialogue, you execute a function called `showDialogue()` .

In your `showDialogue()`, you'll be able to check whether your dialogue was initiated.

Keep your mind off the button. Focus on the `showDialogue()`.

If your dialogue was initiated, then do not execute the rest of your code in `showDialogue()`, as if `showDialogue()` isn't executed twice. It gives an illusion that the multi click isn't working. Is it the solution you desire, without disable and setTimeout?

Comment: thank you,is a good way to solve this problem when show a dialog.for ajax or others  scene when click button so fast,is not a best `common` way.

Comment: In my usual practice, I simply disable the button for three seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Use disabled at first, and then when the dialog displays, enable the button.

Comment: thank you， i need a common way to solve this problem

Comment: @AR7, sorry ,  it's my first answer